# Can not cast value of type NSTaggedPointerString to NSDictionary

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to assign Firebase values to my struct: `var productsArray = [Product]()` however I have a little error:

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to
>   'NSDictionary'.

I know that I can't assign them directly so that is why I am casting like this:

```
self.snusProductTitle = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Products"] as! String
```

And converting:

```
func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {

        return ["Products": snusProductTitle as Any]
    }
```

Like this I append:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (posts) in
            self.productsArray.removeAll()
            var newPostsArray = [Product]()
            for post in posts.children {
                print(posts.value)//Look below image
                let newPost = Product(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPostsArray.insert(newPost, at: 0)
            }

            self.productsArray = newPostsArray
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

And this is minimal Product structure:

```
class Product: NSObject {
    var snusProductTitle: String!


    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    init(snusProductTitle: String) {
        self.snusProductTitle = snusProductTitle
        self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }



    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){
        self.snusProductTitle = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Products"] as! String
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {
        return ["Products": snusProductTitle as Any]
    }
}
```

[image]

While googling, I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: The error message is the solution: `NSTaggedPointerString` is a `NSString`, thus `snapshot.value!` is a string not a dictionary.

Comment: what does `snapshot.value` returns?? did you checked by print `snapshot.value`???

Comment: @macmoonshine That is why I am converting it tho.. @El Captain v2.0, it prints the snapshot while appending the `var productsArray = [Product]()` but as soon as it tries to assign values, it crashes.

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I edited.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp and the function where this line is `self.snusProductTitle = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Products"] as! String` .. add that too

Comment: That is my structure, I add minimal version.

Comment: it prints nothing Optional(Epok Snus) which is one of the childs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127518/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-tarvo-maesepp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.childAdded` gives `FIRDataSnapshot` at a time ... so no need to loop for this .. you just need to pass the current child in your structure.

```
 self.productsArray.removeAll()
 var newPostsArray = [Product]()  

 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: { (posts) in

        let newPost = Product(snapshot: posts as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        newPostsArray.insert(newPost, at: 0)

        self.productsArray = newPostsArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```