# Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSDictionary'. Swift/Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When listening to a new object in Firebase, I get this error: Could not cast value of type `NSTaggedPointerString` to `NSDictionary`. Here is the code that listens to a a user that has registered.

```
FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
     guard let user = user else { return }
     self.user = User(authData: user)

     let userref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(self.user.uid)
     userref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
          print(snapshot.value!)
          var newItems: [UserItem] = []
          for item in snapshot.children {
               let userDetail = UserItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot) /////////// CRASHES HERE //////////
               newItems.append(userDetail)
          }
     self.userItem = newItems
     })
     print(self.user.uid)
}
```

And when the error comes up it points to here:

```
    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:Any] ///// ERROR HERE
        name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        email = snapshotValue["email"] as! String
        age = snapshotValue["age"] as! String
        ref = snapshot.ref
}
```

The console is printing what is inside Firebase correctly and the data is there and it exists, but this casting or data read error keeps happening. It has something to do with the conversion but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: The error message says that `snapshot.value` is not `Dictionary`, it's  `String`.

Comment: So should I write, let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [Dictionary:Any]?

Comment: cause i tried this, let snapshotValue = (snapshot.value as Disctionary) as! [String:Any] but that didn't work

Comment: `as! [Dictionary:Any]?`is still worse, much worse.

Comment: Also tried this, if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                                                
                                                if let username = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                                                    print(username)
                                                }

Comment: The compiler clearly complains that `snapshot.value` is **not** a dictionary

Comment: Ok so if I observe like this, let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users") then it's a dictionary, but how do I access now the child users uid?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase but believe the compiler.

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of your Firebase structure, as text - no images. We need to understand your structure to answer correctly. The snapshot could contain a string, a number, another dictionary, even the dreaded Firebase array. Update your question with that and we'll be able to help.

Comment: You may find your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459460/can-not-cast-value-of-type-nstaggedpointerstring-to-nsdictionary?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Say

```
snapshot.value as! String
```

In this case, the value is a string, so that is what you must cast to.

Comment: The other lines will then have to be deleted.

Comment: but then I get this, Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String' for the other items (name, age, email)

Comment: Did you read my comment? You need to delete the lines about the other items. There are no other items. The value is not a dictionary. It is a string! How many times do you need to be told?

Comment: I did, however, the way the item is set up, I need it to be a dictionary so I can separately access the values. Like so, let detail = UserItem[indexPath.row]      print(detail.name) etc.

Comment: The error tells you that it is _not_ a dictionary. That is reality. You cannot make it be a dictionary. It's a string. That's four times you've been told.

Comment: @matt this is almost the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477489/swift-ios-firebase-not-returning-any-data

Answer (score 0):

it might be the case that you updated your database and the old data did not have the correct format, try deleting your database, add new data and run your program again