# Swift ios Firebase not returning any data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch values live using this function:

```
handle = ref?.child("Users").child(String(itemId)).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapShot) in

                        if let dictionary = snapShot.value as? [String: Any] {
                            print(dictionary)
                            if let profileImageUrl = dictionary["url"] as? String {
                                print(profileImageUrl)
                            }
                        }
                    }, withCancel: nil)
```

I start my app then I go to my firebase console and make some changes to that child but my `print()` never gets fired.

This is how my DB looks like:

```
MyRootDb123
-Users
   --Id (Child of users)
     --- url inside Id
     --- name inside Id
     --- age inside Id
```

Also in my code, what does the `withCancel` function do?

DB structure:
[image]

**Update**
I added `print(snapShot)` which returns:

```
Snap (url) www.someurl.com
```

Comment: which one not fire `print(dictionary)` ?

Comment: @NazmulHasan No one gets fired, this never enters ``if let dictionary = snapShot.value as? [String: Any] {`` I am think I cant use [String: Any]

Comment: @NazmulHasan I added `print(snapShot)` which returns:

    Snap (url) www.someurl.com

Comment: --Id (Child of users)  i could not under what does it mean .. share firebase key name

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have added a screenshot of my db

Comment: U vs u in users. print(snapshot) is printing that because the closure is executing once. The print(dictionary) doesn't print anything because that statement doesn't execute due to the If statement prior to it and the snapshot being nil. Also, you don't need the handle =, unless you are removing that specific observer at a later time. The cancel block will be called if you will no longer receive new events due to no longer having permission.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is case sensitive for node key names so *Users* is not the same as *users* and your code is accessing *users* but the structure is Users.

code

```
handle = ref?.child("users")
```

structure

```
MyRootDb123
-Users
   --Id (Child of users)
```

**Update** to show how to attach an .childChanged observer to the users node and handle a change to a user.

Let's start with a basic Firebase structure

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Leonard"
    url: "www.leonard.com
  uid_1
    name: "Bill"
    url: "www.bill.com"
```

then we attach a .childChanged observer to the users node. When a child in the users node changes, the changed node is passed to the closure.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")

usersRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    let name = userDict["name"] as! String
    let url = userDict["url"] as! String
    print("\(name) now has url of:  \(url)")
})
```

To test this, in the Firebase console we change the url child of uid_0 from www.leonard.com to www.yipee.com, like this

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Leonard"
    url: "www.yipee.com" //here's the new url
  uid_1
    name: "Bill"
    url: "www.bill.com"
```

Since the change was in uid_0, that node it passed to the closure in the code above and will print:

```
Leonard now has url of:  www.yipee.com
```

Comment: I made a typo in my post. My code seem to work coz when I call ``print(snapShot)`` it outputs **"Snap (url) www.someurl.com"** but I dont understand how I check my node for a specific value. The output above was printed when I changed my "url" value through the console

Comment: @Kiow The screen shot is showing *Users* and your code is showing *users*. It is case sensitive and will not work with that error. When you print(snapshot) it will print the data that was retrieved from Firebase - because snapshot is blank, it's not printing anything. The code is running, but not *working* as it's not getting anything back from Firebase due to the typo. Fix the typo in your post and your code and we'll take another look at the issue.

Comment: I have now fixed my typo

Comment: But I still dont now I how I can see what value has been updated and to what. Right now I am trying to do something like this: ``snapshot.key == "url" { get value }``

Comment: @Kiow See my answer about how to do this task.